# Large JSON data over POST request

Tags: json, django, post

I have a system working as a swarm, with a lot of independent devices running Django and a main Queen (running Django as well) gathering data from the swam.

Each device from the swarm is sending the new data to the queen using a POST request with the data in a json.
Each data recorded in the device is then updated to mark it as sent to the queen and doesn't need to be resent later.

the problem is that each dataset is about 10 MB and I am getting a timeout error while processing the post request.

The solution I got at the moment is far from optimal:
I split the upload in batches of 500 records and send several post requests.
After each successful upload, I update each record 1 by 1.
This solution has some performance issues.

Things I would need to improve:

1. manage to send all data in 1 single request
2. Reduce the data volume to be sent
3. Update the data faster on each device after

so the questions are:

1. Is there a way to keep the post request alive for longer?
2. I am thinking of using gzip to send the data. Is it something to look into or it is not a good practice?
3. Right now I am looping through each object, update the attribute and save the object. Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: What service are you using to host/run your Django application? Why don't you increase the timeout window?

Comment: I am hosting it on azure. I don't mind increasing it, but where to put the limit? what is considered as "reasonnable"?
it is already set to 30 sec, which  seems to be quite a bit.

Comment: What's the bottleneck in the request/response cycle? 30 seconds is a long time just to transfer 10MB. It's big but it's not huge either. My guess is your queen takes too long to process it. To solve this, you could just save the data temporarily and offload the parsing and processing of said data to a worker queue system (e.g https://pypi.org/project/django-rq/), and immediately respond to the POST request.

Comment: Yes I thing you're right, I'll log the timings when it is starting and stopping and see what really takes time. I'll come back to you soon. Regarding the data, most of the time it is over mobile network with limited speed so I think it still worth checking it, and the json makes it easy to compress. Is gzip a good option?